# What is the word for "Vegan" in Russian? (NOT Vegetarian)

Tags: грамматика

I cannot find anywhere how to say vegan in russian, only vegetarian.

Comment: I'm russian, and there is no "веган". Никто так не говорит, но надо дурить людей. (It sounds stupid, you have to say вегетарианец, maybe kids in school could say in other stupid way, which only they understand.)

Comment: You say so just because you simply don't know about it. Here's [a vegan group in ВКонтакте](http://vk.com/veganism), in Russian, they all use the word `веган`.

Comment: @user4435 Статья о веганах в википедии: [Веганство](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD).

Answer (score 14):

It is `веган` or (rarely) `веганец` in Russian, the word is a typical internationalism. The word for "veganism" is `веганство` (analogous to "вегетарианство") or just `веганизм`. This word has appeared pretty recently in Russian, so no major dictionary has it (some of the newest ones [do have it](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/321819/%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD)), but in the Russian Wiki there is [an article about it](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE).